# Changing property value of Array of Objects without recreating the entire Object

Tags: angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework, ionic5

**How to change a single element in an array of object without recreating the entire object?**

I have an array of objects like so

```
objArr = [{
  icon: 'add',
  iconAdd: 'add',
  iconRemove: 'remove',
  expand: false
},
{
  icon: 'add',
  iconAdd: 'add',
  iconRemove: 'remove',
  expand: false
}]
```

My function gets the ID of the clicked element and then I want to update the expand element for that index.

```
updateObjArr(index) {
  this.objArr[index].expand = !this.objArr[index].expand
}
```

However, this updates **ALL** the expand values in the array. When I really only want to update the specified index.

I've tried assigning the current index object to a temp variable and then changing it that way but the same issue occurs.

```
let tempItemHolder = this.objArr[index];
tempItemHolder.expand = !tempItemHolder.expand;

this.objArr[index] = tempItemHolder;
```

The only thing I found works was creating the entire object

```
updateObjArr(index) {
  this.objArr[index] = {
                         icon: 'add',
                         iconAdd: 'add',
                         iconRemove: 'remove',
                         expand: true
                       }
}
```

But this seems unnecessary when I just want to change a single value, the iconAdd and iconRemove always will remain the same.

Was there any other way? Or is this how Typescript objects work?

**EDIT**

The error most likely is a result of how I've set things up. It's an NgFor loop that goes over my content, as I'm trying to build an Accordion list (without creating an extra component).

OnClick, I pass in index I for that element and update the expand state. I've just updated the entire index block instead and it works fine, could someone close this question?

Comment: The code snippet provided is logically correct. Can you provide more information, like the function that calls updateObjArray() method, or mehtod(s) that are called in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there must be something more going on because `this.objArr[index].expand = !this.objArr[index].expand` will only update the object at the specified index. I would suspect either you are using the same object repeatedly in creating the array or the update function is getting called with every index.

When I say using the same object I mean something like:

```
let newObj = {
  icon: 'add',
  iconAdd: 'add',
  iconRemove: 'remove',
  expand: false
};

let objArray = [newObj, newObj, newObj];
```

In that event every element of the array is a reference to the same object, so changing a value in one will appear to change them all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
this.updateObjArr(1);

   updateObjArr(index) {
    this.objArr[index].expand = !this.objArr[index].expand;
  }
```